# Storing an objects values into a new object, do they share the same values

Tags: c#

So I've been teaching myself C# the last few months and decided to work on a project to see what I can do with what I have learnt.

So my question is this. Is this new Person selectedPerson a **new object** stored in new memory, or is it a **reference** of the **returned person[i]** in the WhosBuying() Method.
Basically what I'm asking is, do they share the same properties, so if I update one it'll update the other **or** are they different objects.

```
//Chose the person whos buying something and save into selectedPerson
Person selectedPerson = new Person();
selectedPerson = selectedPerson.WhosBuying(person);

    public Person WhosBuying(List<Person> person)
    {
        StringBuilder buyer = new StringBuilder();
        buyer.Append("Who's Buying? ");

        //Loop through all persons: (1)person[0].Name (2)person[1].Name
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var p in person)
        {
            buyer.Append("(" + (i) + ")" + p.Name + " ");
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(buyer);
        string buying = Console.ReadLine();

        //Store the person buying into selectedPerson 
        //by returning the person selected by user input

        for (int x = 1; x < person.Count + 1; x++)
        {
            if (int.Parse(buying) == x)
                return person[x - 1];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: A new instance is created with: Person selectedPerson = new Person(); IMO, Person.WhosBuying should be a static method. Then you will not create this instance that you immediately let loose on the next line. Also this loop is unnecessary - you should parse the index once and then check if it's within the list.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a general answer (but long), because that question can have different answers.

I'll start by defining few things (not because these are the right definitions):
Value: The value which some expression returns, or stored in a variable.
Data: the actual data (ie: the text of a string, etc) of that expression/variable.

In .Net there are two types of expressions/variables: value types, and reference types.

Value types: The value of a value type's expression/variable, is always the data itself. When you store it in a variable, it's the data which copied to that variable - and when you send it as an argument to a method, that data is copied to the method's parameter.

Reference types: The value of a reference type's expression/variable, is always a reference (a pointer if you know what that is) to the data, which stored in another place. When you store it in variable, it's the reference which is copied to that variable - so they both referencing the same data. When you send is as an argument to a method, that reference is copied to the method's parameter, so that method gets a reference to the same data.

Now, all the basic types (except `object`, `string` and arrays), every `enum`, and every type which you define as `struct` - are all value type.
`object`, `string`, every array, delegate, every anonymous type, and every type which you define as `class` is reference type - and the data for a reference type, is (almost) always created with the `new` operator.

And because you didn't specified the definition to `Person`, you're answer cannot be answered definitely. But as most types you'll encounter are reference types, it is most probably a reference type (which means that `WhoIsBuying` returns a reference to the `Person`'s actual data).

Answer (score 0):

At first, "selectedPerson" in your main procedure is a blank "new person", a variable that is pointing to a new object.

After the "WhosBuying" method completes, the variable "selectedPerson" is pointing at whatever the method returns.  It could be a null or it could be another person (aka "p") you dug out of the list that was passed to the method.

I agree with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457122/storing-an-objects-values-into-a-new-object-do-they-share-the-same-values/22457123?noredirect=1#comment34156778_22457122) that this is not a good practice to have this method be an instance method; that it's functionality would make more sense as a static method.  It will work as you have it, but you are creating and destroying an extra object for no reason.